# Passing Optional parameters not calling to the correct one

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, optional-parameters

Little stuck with Parameters, market and sort are optional

```
Route::get('Category/{title}/{market?}/{sort?}', 'HomeController@productList');
```

But when i do this in the URI

url:  Category/title/?sort=3

it doesn't register as 3 for sort but goes in as the market paramater

of course if the URI was Category/title/Makert/3 it will return what i want

```
public function productList($title, $market = null, $sort = null)
{
    // Gets the Categories with its Markets
    $categorys= Product::cats();
    $brands = Product::CategoryWithMarket($title, $market)->groupBy('Brand')->get();
    $subCat = Product::where('Category', $title)->groupBy('Market')->orderBy('Market', 'ASC')->get();

    if (!$market) {
        $marketList = Product::where('Category', $title)->orderBy('Brand', 'ASC')->orderBy('Label', 'ASC')->paginate(15);
        $brands     = Product::where('Category', $title)->groupBy('Brand')->orderBy('Brand', 'ASC')->get();
        $mainTitle  = ucfirst($title);
    }

    else {
        // Gets the list of products with the catery and market attributes arranged by the brand of product
        $marketList = Product::CategoryWithMarket($title, $market)->paginate(15);
        $mainTitle =  ucfirst($title) . ' ' . ucfirst($market) ;
    }

    return $sort;
```

In theroy it should pass back the sort parameter which is 3 but it doesnt return anything, so my question is how do i get sort to return its value 3 rather than being null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Router only uses the path to match the routes and only path parameteres are injected to the controller. So if you you want **sort** to be passed to the controller from the router you need to put that in the path (**/{sort?}**), not in the query (**?sort=3**).

If you want to access query parameters in your controller, you can do this via **$request** object (if it's your action's argument) or **Request** facade:

```
public function someAction() {
  echo Request::query('sort');
}
```